# Problem understanding Linked Lists in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, data-structures, linked-list

I'm learning about data structures and algorithms and I'm starting to learn about constructing linked lists from scratch in python. Right now I understand how they work and the components that go into making them (Nodes, data/address, Head/Tail, etc), but I'm having a really hard time wrapping my brain around how they function when constructing them in python. Like I have working code to make them in python here but I don't get the logic behind how they operate with classes. For example, I'm confused in my addLast-function on how the node variable(***node = Node(value)***) connects to the Node class.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    
    def addLast(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        # NODE POINTS TO THE NEXT ELEMENT IF PROVIDED ELSE NONE
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        # INIT AN EMPTY LINKED LIST
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    
    def addLast(self, value):
        # CREATE A NODE OBJECT WITH VALUE 'value' WHICH POINTS TO NOTHING (because it's the end of the linked list)
        node = Node(value)
        # IF NO HEAD IT BECOMES THE HEAD AND THE TAIL
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
        else:
            # ADD THE NODE TO THE END (tail) OF THE LINKED LIST
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node

# Create an empty linked_list
head = Linked_list()
# Add at the end a node with the value 1
head.addLast(1)
```

Hope it's clearer for you, ask questions if needed

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped immensely with understanding Linked Lists using classes in python. Helped give a lot of clarity and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) may help you understand what the code actually do hedind the scenes.

You can paste the following code to the link and click the "**Visualize Execution**" button. It will visualize all details step by step.

Good Luck!

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    
    def addLast(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node
            
head = LinkedList()
head.addLast(1)
head.addLast(2)
```

Comment: This is actually a really cool way to visually depict code, never knew this was a thing, thanks.